# How to parse 「Nを相手に、」

Tags: particle-に, particle-を

I've gotten to the level where I can start going through some basic Japanese material and largely understand all of it, but there are some times where I'm confused by particle usage, and I'm not sure if it's due to colloquial contractions and omissions.

In this case, I've started to go through the game Mother 2, and although I can understand what the following sentence means overall, I'm not quite sure how the particles are used.

For context, the Onett city police chief is talking to the main character, who just beat some policemen.

The entire sentence is [オネット警察のつわものを相手に、これほどの力を見せるとは…]

Specifically, what is happening with the を相手に part?

If I remove を相手, making [オネット警察のつわものに、これほどの力を見せるとは…], the meaning of the different particles is easily distinguishable, basically translating to [To think that you could show our strong policemen such power..]

What does the を相手 do? As far as I can tell, the sentence is making  つわもの a direct object, but 相手 is a noun. Is して being omitted or something?

Comment: The sentence is basically saying _To think that you had such power as to be able to compete (fight?) with our policemen_

Comment: ＠naruto Following that link, would it then translate to [With our strong policemen as your opponent, to think that you would show such power...] ?

Comment: For the first part, yes, sort of. As for the sentence-end とは, see http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/30285/5010

Comment: @naruto Thank you for the links, they have been very helpful. Just to check, is there anything sort of off with the first part?