# What does とは mean in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, translation

> Sentence:まさかあれだけやって起きんとは...
> Translate: (I didn't expect) No matter what I do, he won't wake up.

What does とは mean at the end of this sentence?

Comment: See also: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/30166/9831

Answer (score 1):

When used at the end of a sentence, とは often shows surprise or disbelief. It is often translated as "To think that...". Here are some examples:

> もう今年も１２月とは。
> To think that it's already December this year too!

> 彼はこういうことをするとは！ 
> To think that he would do something like this!

Do not confuse this with case particle と + topic marker は (彼とは付き合いたくない = I don't want to go out with him.). とは can also be used to define words as well (ブラックホールとはなんですか？ = what is a "black hole"?). とは only expresses surprise as a final particle.

With this, your sentence would roughly mean:

> まさかあれだけやって起きんとは... 
> To think that he wouldn't wake up even though I did that much...

Comment: Shouldn't it be would wake up? Not wouldn't wake up?

Comment: @user342453 起きん means 起きない. The ん is a negative auxiliary ぬ (ず).