# Understanding あるとは珍しい

Tags: grammar, particle-は, particle-と, conditionals

> 「おおっ、こんなぜいたくな物がうちにある**とは**珍しいね」
> Oh, finding such luxurious presents at our place is unusual.

I'm a bit confused by the と in this sentence. I can only imagine that it is a conditional と. I guess "**if** there are presents at our place it's unusual" makes sense but it seems awkward and it feels to me that it would be equally awkward in Japanese.

Presumably the は is just there for emphasis?

I would have been more comfortable if it had been ある**こと**は (**the fact that** there are presents at our place is unusual) with は just as a normal topic marker. Would this be wrong?

Comment: Do these answer your question: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/25323/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/24976/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/30158/9831

Comment: @Chocolate Ah, yes. I'd forgotten about that usage. How embarrassing. Thanks.