# Why is で necessary in the following sentence?

Tags: grammar, copula

I used Google Translate to say "I'm not Korean."

I expected something like:

> 私は韓国人はない

However, I got this:

> 私は韓国人ではない

Why is the で used in this situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'to be (a thing)' is a bit of an odd complex verb thing, involving both で and ある. Your first sentence, lacking で, simply means 'I have no (inanimate) Koreans'. The negative is, a bit unusually, ではない in most cases rather than just でない, but the で cannot be omitted - it's part of the verb である(～だ), and without it, all you have is ある (which is only 'for an inanimate thing to exist or be located').

Answer (score 2):

If you mean you expected "I'm not Korean." to be written 私は韓国人はない, then it seems you forgot that it's not は, but じゃ.

> 私は韓国人じゃない。

There are several ways of writing this simple negative statement, of varying degrees of politeness/formality.

じゃない。
じゃありません。
ではない。
ではありません。

Someone with a better grasp of grammar can probably tell you what function で plays in this construction...

Actually I found a previous Q&A that applies and goes into slightly more detail in the link below:

[What does では mean in this sentence?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/45020/what-does-%E3%81%A7%E3%81%AF-mean-in-this-sentence)