# What does 訳では mean in the end of sentence?

Tags: meaning

フェイ、まだ、そうと判明した訳では。違う原因かもしれない。

Is it short for 訳ではない?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this means そうと判明した訳ではない.

You may know the omission of ない can happen frequently with [negative polarity items](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/16060/5010) such as ちっとも, 決して, 少しも, and どこにも. Likewise, people know 訳では is almost always followed by a negative predicate (i.e., ない), and thus the predicate can safely be omitted in casual conversations. Note that this は is critically important to indicate something negative will follow. See: [Why is the topic marker often used in negative statements (ではない, ～とは思わない)?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/1077/5010)

Examples:

> - ハサミ? それでは…。 Scissors? I doubt it helps...
> - 明日はちょっと…。 Tomorrow is, well, ... (inconvenient for me...)
> - 「見たい？」「そ、そんなことは！」 "Wanna see it?" "N-No, I...!"