# tamago o yoku tabemasu

Tags: particles, particle-は

> tamago o yoku tabemasu.
>
> kudamono wa amari tabemasen.

Why for the first sentence with tamago, the particle "o" is used
where as for the second sentence with kudamono, particle "wa" is used?

Comment: Hint: It's more to do with the verb than the noun.

Comment: It sounds contranstive to me. "I often eat eggs. (However) I don't eat fruits much (unlike other foods)." There are answered questions on this site regarding the contrastive wa particle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is why "wa" is called a *topic* marker rather than a *subject* marker.

> #### [Topic Marker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topic_marker#Japanese:_%E3%81%AF)
>
> The topic marker is one of many Japanese particles. It is written with the hiragana は, which is normally pronounced *ha*, but when used as a particle is pronounced *wa*. **It is placed after whatever is to be marked as the topic.** If what is to be the topic would have had が (ga), the subject marker, or を ((w)o), the direct object marker, as its particle, those are replaced by は. Other particles (for example: に, と, or で) are not replaced, and は is placed after them. (emphasis mine)

は marks the subject of a sentence only in, say, 80% of the cases. In your case, を was replaced by は because fruit is the (contrasted) topic of the second sentence. Note that this は is also working as a contrast marker. Also note that は is much preferred in negative sentences.

See:

- [What's the difference between wa (は) and ga (が)?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/22/5010)
- [Why is the topic marker often used in negative statements (ではない, ～とは思わない)?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/1077/5010)