# Difference でない and ではない

Tags: particle-は, particle-で

What's the difference between でない and　ではない. I've read some websites. Some websites say that if I use only でない (in some case) it will be awkward.

I currently know that this is a combination between particle で and は. And I understand that は is used just to emphasize the topic.

Comment: Why we use ではない in relative clauses. I've been taught that は can't be used in relative clauses.

Comment: Related: [Why is the topic marker often used in negative statements (ではない, ～とは思わない)?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/1077/5010)

Comment: Related (though it didn't really get an acceptable answer): [ではない in Relative Clauses](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/65347/%e3%81%a7%e3%81%af%e3%81%aa%e3%81%84-in-relative-clauses)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is the topic marker often used in negative statements (ではない, ～とは思わない)?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/1077/why-is-the-topic-marker-often-used-in-negative-statements-%e3%81%a7%e3%81%af%e3%81%aa%e3%81%84-%ef%bd%9e%e3%81%a8%e3%81%af%e6%80%9d%e3%82%8f%e3%81%aa%e3%81%84)