# How to use には and では in the sentence

Tags: particle-に

> 日焼け止めを塗っていれば、そんなことにはならなかっただろうに。

Why did we use には here after こと, what is the meaning? Can anyone explain what is the grammar of には and では

Answer (score 2):

`～ + に + なる` is a basic set phrase that means "to go ～", "to become ～", "to end up with ～", "to turn out to be ～", etc. This に is roughly an equivalent of English "to".

- 大学生になる to become a university student
- 終わりになる to come to an end
- 元気になる to fee/get better, to recover

こと on its own refers to an event. Here, そんなこと refers to the resulting burnt skin, so it can be translated as "such a result/appearance". そんなこと is marked with に. は after に is a [topic/contrast marker used in a negative clause](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/1077/5010).

Therefore:

> 日焼け止めを塗っていれば、
>   If you had put sunscreen on,
>
> そんなことにはならなかっただろうに。
>   (I suppose) You wouldn't have ended up with such an appearance.