# Why is では used here? What does it do to the meaning of this sentence?

Tags: grammar, particles

I came across a sentence that has puzzled me.

> 今度ばかりはいたずら**では**済まされません｡

Why is **では** used here?

Comment: do you have any sense of what the sentence says?  the more you can provide about what you already understand the better we can help you.

Comment: Hi! Someone guilty of pulling pranks stole something important. It upset the village he lives in, and a townsman said to this to their elder. I understand it to mean, "This time we can't just chalk this up to a prank." I don't grammatically understand why that particle was used, although I understand the meaning behind the sentence.

Answer (score 4):

～**で**済む is a set phrase that means "to get away with ～".

> これで済んだと思うなよ。
> You won't get away with this.
>
> ここから落ちたら怪我では済まない。
> If you fall from here, you can't just get hurt and survive.

いたずらで済ませる means "to get away calling it a prank", "to forget thinking of it as a prank", etc. は is used because it's a negative sentence (see: [Why is the topic marker often used in negative statements (ではない, ～とは思わない)?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/1077/5010)).

Answer (score 0):

My student just asked me 2 grammars. "～で済む" and "～ないで済む" can be translated as "get by doing something/done by something"

> 今度ばかりはいたずらでは済まされません｡
> => It can not be done by a joke.

では was used but not で because は is used to show the meaning which is similar to ほど. 強調という役割で使われています。

Comment: @Chocolate: I had a typo. Thank you for correcting.