# ご存じ how to use properly and why

Tags: particles, verbs, nouns, keigo

I found a couple of examples using this noun; neither makes a lot of sense.
i think that ご存じ is an irregular polite form of 知る. However, if that is the case it is a bit odd as the polite form of a verb is a noun, though that wouldn't be the weirdest thing i have encountered with keigo. i have seen it used as **name** をご存じですか can i used any noun is such a way? if so what is the particle?

The other example i have is the following sentence:
ご存知だとは思いますが、クオーターしかつかえませんよ。
which i have a couple questions about; first what the hell does ご存知だ say?　i dont understand the だ at the end of this noun is it a particle or marking past tense of the knowledge? The クオーターしかつかえませんよ is confusing cause it isn't written in kanji but i believe it is クオーターしか使えませんよ。but even that i think should say クオーターしか使えますよ。　as the katakana is quarters しか is nothing but or only and 使える is serviceable or useable/ can be used.

lastly i find the は a bit weird here, why can it go after the と i have never seen that before. (と**は**思いますが) i am assuming it being used to makr the direct object like one can use では or には, etc.

Comment: I think this is too many things to focus on.  You should make a separate topic for questions about ～とは思う.

Comment: Agreed. You have four separate questions here, each of which have simple, direct answers, but it would be much clearer if you split this into four questions for the community to answer.

Comment: @istraci hmm, ok i will in anther hour i didn't think it would be too much as it was just one sentence but, to be fair it is one confusing sentence.

Answer (score 2):

ご存じ is not a verb in the first place. It's a honorific **no-adjective** that has to be used with だ/です. You can think it roughly corresponds to "familiar/aware" with respectful feelings. I don't know why, but there is no direct honorific version of 知っている. Whenever you want to say "someone knows something" with respect, you have to use this no-adjective and say 彼はご存じです and so on. (You may think お知りになっています should work, but we don't usually use this for whatever reason.)

By the way, a humble version of 知る/思う is 存じる, which is an ordinary verb.

This は after と is a contrast marker. It's optional here, and you can drop it without largely changing the meaning.

クオーターしか使えますよ is ungrammatical. しか is a [negative polarity item](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/16060/5010) and must be used with a negative expression. This is a basic rule which has nothing to do with ご存じ, so please recheck your textbook.

> ご存知だとは思いますが、クオーターしか使え【つかえ】ませんよ。
> I think you know this, but you can use only *quarters*.

Comment: doesn’t ご存じるよう function somewhat similarly to しっている. i mean, i know grammatically they’re quite different in form but if you felt the need to express the later couldn’t that be achieved through using ご存じるよう somehow?

Comment: @A.Ellett No, ご存じる(よう) is ungrammatical because it's not a verb.

Comment: I know ご存じる(よう) is not a verb.  I was wondering whether something like, ご存じるようにX and Xと知っている might somehow function equivalently on the semantic level even though the grammar is rather different.  Or, is ご存じるようにX coming across to presumptive?

Comment: @A.Ellett ご存じる is always 100% incorrect. (What is this る if it's not a verb?) BCCWJ has >1200 examples of ご存じ and no example of ご存じる.

Comment: @naruto I've just found this in the novel I'm reading: "[...] ご存じないのですかっ。". It's an official printed book, so I suppose it's not a mistake. If it's not a verb, is it ご存じ + (が) + ない?

Comment: @Haragurodanshi Good question, ご存知でない and ご存じない are used interchangeably (ご存知がない is wrong). I don't know how to break down ご存じない, but maybe you can treat it as a fixed adjective like 問題ない and 不甲斐ない.

Comment: @naruto You've written ご存じでない... Did you mean ご存じではない?

Comment: @Haragurodanshi は is [optional](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/1077/5010). It's typically added in main clauses but is not an integral element of this phrase.